# keycloak external database schema

Tags: database, configuration, keycloak

I'm starting to configure Keycloak to run on production environment and I need to use a database in order to run more than one instance with a single configuration repository. I'm using Oracle as SGBD.
But I didn't find the scripts to create the database in the Keycloak's git.
Does anyone knows where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specifically run a separate set of SQL files.  Keycloak will run it for you on first startup.

A bit of advice as it's not really obvious at first - you'll either need to remove and install the default Keycloak data source (KeycloakDS) or manually modify the standalone.xml to point to the setup you want.  It took me a little bit to figure out the order that I needed to do things.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, We did those DS configurations for apiman (btw, this one has 2 scripts wich you need to run first). Did you try to run the first time with DDL permission and remove those permissions after? I'm not confortable( :) ) with letting a app user with DDL permissions in production environment.

Comment: There is no reason you couldn't do that at least initially.  I have my Keycloak in it's own environment on it's own AWS RDS instance - it can do what it wants to the DB.  I'd be concerned about future upgrades if you take away DDL permissions but you could test that before each upgrade.

Comment: The application is in production environment. In my opinion isn't a good pratice to run a service with DDL grants. If I need to upgrade, I'll run keycloak once to upgrade and change the database user to the one with only DML grants again.

Comment: By the way: it worked. This is what I did:
1) I have 2 DB users: the schema Owner and the app user;
2) Run Keycloak with schema owner once to let it set up the database;
3) Stop keycloak;
4) Change DB user to "app user" (only DML grants);
5) Run Keycloak again.